# Overcoming some Scala type system limitations

Tags: scala, generics, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, type-systems

While trying to implement a version of the simply typed lambda calculus, I encountered what seem to be limitations of the Scala (2.13.1) type system.

The code below does not compile, even though I believe that all the types can be inferred to match via [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)). So are the type system's inference capabilities incomplete (or am I missing something)?

If so, how to circumvent these limitations and fix the code below to make it compile (while preserving its intended semantics)?

Note that my code does not dynamically depend on generic type arguments, so the problem is not due to type erasure.

```
def eval[A <: T[A]](expression: T[A]): A = expression match {
  case n@Nat(_) => n
  case a@Abs(_) => a
  case App(f, e) => eval(eval(f).f(eval(e)))
  case Fix(f) =>
    val s = eval(f).f(s)
    eval(s)
}

sealed trait T[Type <: T[Type]]
final case class Nat(v: BigInt) extends T[Nat]
final case class Abs[I <: T[I], O <: T[O]](f: (=> T[I]) => T[O]) extends T[Abs[I, O]]
final case class App[I <: T[I], O <: T[O]](f: T[Abs[I, O]], e: T[I]) extends T[O]
final case class Fix[I <: T[I], O <: T[O]](f: T[Abs[Abs[I, O], Abs[I, O]]]) extends T[Abs[I, O]]
```

Current compile errors (cleaned up to match the code above):

```
Error:(2, 20) type mismatch;
     found   : n.type (with underlying type Nat)
     required: A
        case n@Nat(_) => n
Error:(3, 20) type mismatch;
     found   : a.type (with underlying type Abs[Any,Any])
     required: A
        case a@Abs(_) => a
Error:(4, 36) inferred type arguments [Any] do not conform to method eval's type parameter bounds [A <: T[A]]
        case App(f, e) => eval(eval(f).f(eval(e)))
Error:(4, 41) type mismatch;
     found   : T[Any]
     required: T[A]
    Note: Any >: A, but trait T is invariant in type Type.
    You may wish to define Type as -Type instead. (SLS 4.5)
        case App(f, e) => eval(eval(f).f(eval(e)))
Error:(4, 40) type mismatch;
     found   : A
     required: T[Any]
    Note: A <: Any (and A <: T[A]), but trait T is invariant in type Type.
    You may wish to define Type as +Type instead. (SLS 4.5)
        case App(f, e) => eval(eval(f).f(eval(e)))
Error:(6, 23) recursive value s needs type
          val s = eval(f).f(s)
```

P.S.: The last error is due to a missing type annotation. However, I would need to get the type parameters `I` and `O` of `Fix(f)` in order to specify the type of `s`.

Comment: The compiler is unable to prove that `n` will only be returned when `A` in fact is `Nat`. I know there is a valid explanation for this, but I do not remember which one it was. Anyways, usually you can solve this problem using a **typeclass**.

Comment: BTW Why you need the **F-Bounded** polymorphism here?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess `Type` is the Scala type of a node in abstract syntax tree.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `Type` is the type of the Lambda-calculus expression. There might be other ways to do it; this is one way of keeping track of the type of the application expression.